# Predicting one time series based on another

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting, prediction

I have two thermometers A, B which measure the air temperature over 2 months every hour.
At a certain point thermometer B breaks but A keeps working.
I need to predict the B values according to A's.

So I have two time series of which I can deduct trends and periodicity. Now that I have residuals, how should I proceed? Should I cluster every A's temperature value and its relative B values? I would end up having more than one Y for every X. How can I proceed?

Comment: Do you have to predict the nonsense values that B is showing after it broke? Or do you have to predict the temperatures at location B? If the latter, why don't you start with estimating a simple regression $B_t=\beta_0+\beta_1 A_t+\varepsilon_t$ and using the fitted coefficients $\hat\beta_0$ and $\hat\beta_1$ and the actual values of $A_t$ to predict $B_t$?